# Optimal way to build this simple database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a field of application that can have many category
And each category can have many field of application.
(M:M)

Each category can have many language (1:M)

Each category can have many description according to the field of application and the language.

Which is the best way? A or B

[image: data]

When i want to retrieve the description of a category in language english and of the field.name = 'house' the solution A seems better.

However,

because description is not directly linked to category, when I make user be able to insert a new category, user will provide me a list of field for that category:
For example:
INSERT: this category (e.g. leather has 2 field of application E.G house and car. SO i want the user be able to insert 2 french description of category, one for house and one for car, and 2 english decription, one for house and one for car.
If that category would have 3 field of application then i need 3 description in french and 3in english.

The solution B seems easier

Since description is not directly tied to field, is possible to make user insert just the description of the field that that category has?
EDIT
OR another option

[image: a]

/EDIT

EDIT B

Description describe a category, the description change according to which language i am and which field of use i am.

For example, category: leather Field: Home Language:english Description: Leather is optimal for home
other

Category:leather Field:car Language:english: leather is optimal for clean a car

And so on

---

### ## EDIT D: ##

Field: It's the field: For example: Sailing, House, Outdoor, Car.
Category it's the category of the product example: Leather, simil leather, cloth

A category can have many field of use (e.g. leather can be used in house and outdoor, and cloth in car and sailing, etc)
A field can have many category(e.g. in the field of sailing can be used cloth and leather, in outdoor, can be used leather and simil leather)

Each category has a name that need to change according to 3 language and a description of that category that need to change according to language AND according to the field.

My problem is:

1) The description of a category change according to the field and to the language:

Example: 
a)language: en, 
field: sailing, 
category: leather 
description: Our leather is optimal for sailing and boat because it's water resistant.[this is english language and the description of the category is in english relative to how good leather is for sailing]

b)language:italian, 
field sailing(this will be in italian too), 
category: leather(in italian) 
description: La nostra pelle va bene per la nautica perche è acqua resistente[this is italian language and the description of the category is in italian relative to how good leather is for sailing]

c)language english 
field:outdoor, 
category:leather, 
description: Our leather is optimal for outdoor because it is UV resistant [this is english language and the description of the category is in english relative to how the leather (category) is optimal for outdoor]

D)language italian 
field: outdoor(this will be in italian too) 
category:leather (in italian) 
description: La nostra pelle va bene per l'esterno(outdoor) perche è UV resistente. [this is italian language and the descriprion of the category is in italian relative to how the leather is optimal for outdoor]

E) language:english
field:sailing
category: cloth
description: Our cloth is optimal for sailing

F) language:italian
Field:sailing(in italian)
category:cloth(in italian)
Description: Our cloth is optimal for sailing (this would be in italian)

F) language:english
Field:outdoor
category:cloth
Description: Our cloth is optimal for outdoor because...

Of course a category must be present in the field(e.g. if simil leather is not in the field of sailing it will not have a sailing description)

I hope now it's more clear

### EDIT E

i end up doing like this:

[image: a]

Like this i am able to control which field i am, which category, and which language i am, so i'll be able to change description according to : Category, field, and language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link between category and language has me confused. By the `id_category` field in `language`,  you claim that every language has one category, or is associated with one category, or something like this. I doubt that.

The way I understand your example, every description is characterized by a language, a field and a category. Since the combination of field and category are already modeled by that `field_category` table, and that has its own ID, you could make every description reference `field_category.id` and `language.id`. You can combine both together to form a unique key.

According to your examples, the fields and categories would need translations as well. So you'd need two more tables, one to hold the translations for each. Each translation of a field would reference the field and the language, both together forming a unique key. Likewise for categories.

Something [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/036aa5):

[image: ER Diagram]

```
create table field (
  id bigint primary key,
  name varchar(255) -- this is not translated
);
create table category (
  id bigint primary key,
  image varchar(255) -- or whatever type you need
);
create table field_category (
  id_field bigint not null,
  id_category bigint not null,
  foreign key (id_field) references field(id),
  foreign key (id_category) references category(id),
  primary key (id_field, id_category)
);
create table language (
  id bigint primary key,
  language char(5)  -- or whatever you use to name languages
);
create table description (
  id_field bigint not null,
  id_category bigint not null,
  id_language bigint not null,
  description text,
  foreign key (id_field, id_category)
    references field_category(id_field, id_category),
  foreign key (id_language) references language(id),
  primary key (id_field, id_category, id_language)
);
create table field_name (
  id_field bigint not null,
  id_language bigint not null,
  name varchar(255),
  foreign key (id_field) references field(id),
  foreign key (id_language) references language(id),
  primary key (id_field, id_language)
);
create table category_name (
  id_category bigint not null,
  id_language bigint not null,
  name varchar(255),
  foreign key (id_category) references category(id),
  foreign key (id_language) references language(id),
  primary key (id_category, id_language)
);
```

Comment: I take your example and modified a bit, see if it's ok, but i don't know where to put name of the category now ( that change just with language and not with field) Should i put in the Language table too?

Comment: See the last sentence from my post, “likewise for categories”. Means you need a separate table for the translations of the categories, and each translation of a category would reference the category and the language, both together forming a unique key.

Comment: but with my solution, i can give a field and a caegory and a language, identify the description for that category according the feld and according the language. I just need to change category description according to field and according to language

Comment: @user3384514: I had something [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/036aa5) in mind, although I can't seem to turn that into UML as easily as I'd have hoped.

Comment: thank you  much, btw, how much this is true:
Composite primary & foreign keys should be discouraged & avoided as those create maintenance & performance overhead into the database layer. An auto-increment/serial primary key with a compound unique key should be used instead.

Also for the sake of same performance reasons, primary keys should not be made up of columns of string values as no matter how optimistic indexing you’d apply to strings, their performance will incrementally decreased over time as with increase of volume of records to be indexed.

Comment: @user3384514: Maintainance is a matter of taste imho. For performance, benchmarks are the ultimate test, but I'd consider my approach suprtior here. You'll need the two column unique constraint to ensure consistency, so you need that key. And adding anything besides that key is only adding overhead. As it stands, you can *read* from `description, field, category, language` without even including `field_category` in the query. Only when inserting will you use it to check consistency, and even then you only need the index.

Comment: so the only autoincrement key is the id in table field, category, language. all the other depends on this 3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49931/discussion-between-mvg-and-user3384514)

Answer (score 0):

It is not getting clear what description is about. Does description describe the entries of "Field" in different languages? Then your third option is correct, the connection is missing in the other ones.

Or is description the description of a category? Then your option A is correct.

In option B, you have two "paths" from description to category - is this what you want? Can a description be say category A and belong to language English which is category B? I guess your option B is simply wrong...

After edit B:
Your Model A is correct. B would make inconsistencies possible, while C is just wrong - the description has nothing to do with "field", right?

Another Edit:
Now it's getting clearer. To design a correct data model it is often helpful to describe every relation in sentenses. I think there is still missing some information and the correct model is different from all three you have shown here.

Comment: Actually, the description change according to language AND according to field, BEcause first i had the description field in language table. And each description for each field was separated by / so i can pick up the right one but they told me is bad, so i needed to create a subtable, trying to connect description of the category both depend on which language i choose and which field i am.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think the situation is not clear enough anymore. Too many wild guesses are left! I need a more complete description of all the data you want to store.

Comment: Yes it gets much clearer now. Your approaches are all not quite correct I think. You need more tables, one language specific for field and one for category. I would introduce another table for the languages (even if there are only 3 rows in that table, doesn't really matter)